# MySQL Full Textsearch multiple fields

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have some table like this:

```
car/model
Audi A2 2.0 TDI
Audi A8 2.5 TDI
Audi A6 4.2 V8
```

From PHP I get this var: 'Audi A8'

When I run this query:

```
select * from cars where match(car, model) against ('Audi A8')
```

MySQL returns:

```
Audi A2 2.0 TDI
Audi A8 2.5 TDI
Audi A6 4.2 V8
```

I only want 'Audi A8 2.5 TDI'. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Split the value to firstname and lastname:

```
$names = explode( ' ', $value );
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string( $names[ 0 ] );
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string( $names[ 1 ] );
```

and run the query:

```
mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM people WHERE Firstname = '$firstname' AND Lastname = '$lastname'" );
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, I'm looking for a Full Textsearch solution. I clearified by question some more with some cars. Also, I don't want to use 'LIKE', too slow, my dataset is too big.